# Is there a specific word or phrase for the drowsiness one might feel soon after a heavy lunch?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage, colloquialisms

After a lunch, especially a nutritionally dense one, one might drift off into a drowsy state, sort of a "I sure could use a nap" feel, likely due to the breaking down of the foods in the digestive tract.

Is there a specific, common word or phrase for that drowsy feel/condition?

Example of a relatively dense meal:

> - First course: artichoke (2 helpings)
> - Main course: steam cooked blood sausage (2 helpings); garlic/parsley flavored shiitake mushrooms and potatoes cooked in duck fat (2 helpings)
> - A portion of camembert accompanied by a half glass of red wine
> - Dessert: a handful of walnuts; a square of dark chocolate
> - Hot beverage: green tea to wash down the whole thing

Comment: I would suggest the word _food coma_, though it is very colloquial.

Comment: +1 but are you looking for a technical term or a colloquial one?

Comment: I've never heard the two following words/phrases in the answers below used to describe this fatigue.  Doesn't mean they are not used but I've never heard them.  The common reaction/expression to over indulgence I witness is a push back of a chair followed by an breathy "I'm stuffed."  A nap follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sometimes referred to as a '*[Postprandial dip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postprandial_dip)*'!

> In medicine and specifically endocrinology, postprandial dip is a term used to refer to mild hypoglycemia occurring after ingestion of a heavy meal.
>
> *www.wikipedia.org*

It can also be called the ['afternoon slump' or 'post lunch dip'](https://www.sharecare.com/health/energy-boosters/article/getting-over-the-afternoon-slump)

Answer (score 1):

***[The Itis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postprandial_somnolence)*** is what it is called!

> Postprandial somnolence (colloquially known as a food coma, carb coma, or in the African-American community the ***itis***) is a normal state of drowsiness or lassitude following a meal.

[Wikipedia]

Perhaps derived from the suffix "*-itis*" which is a suffix largely associated with illness and diseases.

Also, as [@jera](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/153022/jera) suggests, ***[food coma](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=food%20coma)*** seems to be a widely used and recognized term.

> a state of sleep or extreme lethargy induced by the consumption of a large amount of food.

[Google Definition]

Comment: That sounds like 'ictus'..... He had an 'itis' soon after lunch...

Comment: @Josh61 - You mean it could also be called "ictus"?